# Overlay with circle cutout doesn't show in Safari

Tags: html, css

so I have this code:

```css
    .background-image {
      height: 700px;
      width: 100%;
      background: red;
    }
    
    .top {
        margin-top: -85px;
        position: relative;
        height: 700px; 
    }
    .top .circle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        z-index: 1; 
    }
    .top .circle:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9999px rgba(43, 54, 69, 0.75);
        z-index: -1; 
      }
```

```html
<div class="top">
   <div class="background-image"></div>
   <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

The result is overlay over the red background, with circle cut out in the middle of that. You can see results here: https://jsfiddle.net/erLqg448/

That code works great in Firefox and Chrome but in safari, that whole overlay seems to be missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently safari has a problem with such a large value of spread-radius. But if you use a smaller value, like 99em it should cover your viewport and still render properly. Take a look at above snippet and [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erLqg448/2/)

```css
    .background-image {
      height: 700px;
      width: 100%;
      background: red;
    }
    
    .top {
        margin-top: -85px;
        position: relative;
        height: 700px; 
    }
    .top .circle {
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        z-index: 1; 
    }
    .top .circle:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 99em rgba(43, 54, 69, 0.75);
        z-index: -1; 
      }
```

```html
<div class="top">
   <div class="background-image"></div>
   <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```